# Zk integrating lightbox.js

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, lightbox, zk

I am being able to use [lightbox.js](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/) to view images in ZK framework only if I hardcode the image URL. I need a way to set the URL from the ViewModel but I am not being able to achieve so. Here is what I have done so far :

```
<zk apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.shahukhalroshan.vm.TestVM')" xmlns:h="native">
    <style src="lightbox.css" />
    <div>
        <h:a class="example-image-link" href="http://www.quicksprout.com/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg" data-lightbox="example-1">
            <image id="imgUrl" sclass="example-image" src="http://www.quicksprout.com/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />
        </h:a>
     </div>
     <script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
</zk>
```

Replacing the src as follows doesn't work :

```
<h:a class="example-image-link" href="@load(vm.imageUrl)" data-lightbox="example-1">
   <image id="imgUrl" sclass="example-image" src="@load(vm.imageUrl)" width="100px" height="100px" />
</h:a>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: can you create a working fiddle (http://zkfiddle.org/) on your first case? Like this I know what it has to do.

Comment: ya, i am trying to make zk fiddle but I am not being able to save

Comment: here you go .. http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2j6rb50/1-Zk-Integration-with-lightbox-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first.
You **can't** declare a viewmodel the `zk` tag.

When changing the `zk` tag to a `window` I have acces to the viewmodel but of course still not going right.

So I added some JQuery in the getter to get it fixed.

### Zul :

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('pkg$.TestVM')" xmlns:h="native">
    <div>
        <h:a id="anchor" class="example-image-link" data-lightbox="example-1">
            <image id="imgUrl" sclass="example-image" src="@load(vm.url)" width="100px" height="100px"/>
        </h:a>
    </div>
</window>
```

### TestVM.java:

```
private String url = "http://www.quicksprout.com/images/foggygoldengatebridge.jpg";

public String getUrl() {
    Clients.evalJavaScript("jq('#anchor')[0].href='" + url + "';");
    return url;
}
```

[Working fiddle found here.](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2j6rb50/4-Zk-Integration-with-lightbox-js)